# Spyder 2.3.0beta3 autocompletes automatically after a period

Tags: python, ide, spyder

In the editor, if my first line of code is:

```
obj1.attribute1.subAttribute = 1
```

and I go to the next line and type `obj1.`, as soon as get to <kbd>.</kbd>, it autocompletes automatically, adding `attribute1`.

Is this a bug or can this behavior be turned off?

(Spyder 2.3.0beta3, running Python 3.3.2 on Ubuntu 13.10)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I need to deselect `Automatic Code Completion` from `Preferences`>`Editor`>`Code Introspection/Analysis`.

[image]

For the case that these options don't appear and there's a warning saying you don't have Rope, you need to install [Rope for Python 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rope_py3k/0.9.3-1).   For Ubuntu, you can download from the link, extract the folder, cd into it, and use the command `sudo checkinstall python3 setup.py install`.  Restart Spyder, and you'll have these options.